# Is there a way to set the validation condition to "strictly greater than"?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I would like to know instead of the Hibernate validator @Min which is inclusive (equal or greater than) is there a way to express "strictly greater than" a number?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with the built-in constraints. You would need a custom constraints. But if you are dealing with integers you can always use @Min with your limit + 1.

Comment: Agree, this is the only way :)

Answer (score 10):

If you work with Bean Validation 1.1 (part of Java EE 7) you may use `@DecimalMin` instead which has an additional attribute, `inclusive`, which controls whether "strictly greater than" or "greater than or equals to" semantics are used.

Comment: e.g. @DecimalMin(value = "0.0", inclusive = false)